# Storing RTSP to a file location

Tags: c#, winforms, rtsp, vlc

I am able to stream an rtsp on windows 7 64 bit machine through C# Winform application. This is the library i used - [VLCDotNet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) and here is the code sample to play the RTSP stream:

```
LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(@"rtsp://192.168.137.73:554/live.sdp");
vlcControl1.Media = media;
vlcControl1.Play();
```

I would like to store the streams to a file in my PC on a button click and stop the same with another button. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media1
= new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia("rtsp://192.168.137.73:554/live.sdp");

media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,
scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,
dst=D:\\123.mp4}");

VlcControl control = new VlcControl();
control.Media = media;
control.Play();
```

Comment: hello, this code stores the rtsp stream to a mp4 file? I have a project where I receive RTP packets with H264 payload in them, will this code work for me?

Comment: @user1662033: Yes it stores rtsp stream to mp4 file. You can try this code and check if it works for you.

Comment: wait.. isn't this code for a local stream? In my case I have a server in my LAN streaming RTP to me.. the file is a .mkv file (stream path is "rtsp://192.168.30.11/MyVideo.mkv"). is the code good for that?

Comment: Tried to use code - I get exception "cannot set up option while media is not initialized yet". the code is in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717931/how-to-convert-rtp-h-264-payload-into-playable-file-using-media-foundation

Answer (score 1):

```
VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.LogInFile = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.ShowLoggerConsole = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.Verbosity = VlcLogVerbosities.Debug;

// Disable showing the movie file name as an overlay
// VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-video-title-show");                
// VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-audio");
VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--rtsp-tcp"); //this line was important to make this work
```

Comment: Could you please explain in text how this is a solution to the question?

Comment: To make the rtsp protocol work you need to enter this line VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--rtsp-tcp");  For debugging I added those debug statements, and then you can add the answer posted by Vinshi.

Answer (score 1):

As of Vlc.DotNet.Core 2.1.62, The way to do this is use the extra `opts` param of the `.Play` on the vlc control.

```
var opts = new string[] { @":sout=file/ogg:C:\video.ogg" };
vlc.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri(videoURI), opts);
```

`