# play stream cam with vlc.dotnet

Tags: c#, h.264, vlc, rtsp

I have VLC 2.1.3 and use Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920.

I tried play stream with RTSP but cannot work. I get information about "failed to open/read to DVD". This code is right? What change in this code?

```
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia("dshow:// :dshow-vdev=\"Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920\"");

media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtp://:8554/stream}:sout-all :sout-keep");
VlcControl control = new VlcControl();
control.Media = media;
control.Play();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing RTSP to a file location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071652/storing-rtsp-to-a-file-location)

Answer (score -3):

```
        VlcControl vlc = new VlcControl();
        //LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(@"C:\Users\pgu001\Downloads\Storage_Shipping_Container_Tilt_Bed_Trailer_Delive.avi");

        //Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media1 = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia("rtsp://admin:admin@172.16.22.61:554/live.");
        //media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=D:\\123.mp4}");
        panel1.Controls.Add(vlc);
        vlc.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        vlc.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
        vlc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        vlc.Name = "test";
        vlc.Rate = 0.0F;

        vlc.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);

        //Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(@"rtsp://172.16.22.61:554/live.sdp");
        LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(@"rtsp://172.16.22.61:554/live");
        vlc.Media = media;
        vlc.Play();
```