# How to convert RTP H.264 payload into playable file using Media Foundation

Tags: c#, video, ms-media-foundation

I need a way to be able to make a video file from H.264 RTPFrames (Payload Type 96) that I receive using the Managed Media Aggregation - https://net7mma.codeplex.com/.

I am trying to use media foundation in managed code.

I saw http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/ but I couldn't find how to do it.
I saw that someone said in some forum that it is better to use the Media Foundation dlls in C# managed code.

Does anybody have any experience working with this?

**EDIT:**

I an trying to use the VLCDotNet to put the h264 frames into a video file - here is my code

```
private void StoreFile()
{

    Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = @"C:\Users\Ofek\Desktop\VideoLAN\VLC";
    Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.Initialize();

    media1 = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.LocationMedia("rtsp://192.168.30.11/1.mkv");         

    media1.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,
    scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,
    dst=D:\\123.mp4}");

    VlcControl control = new VlcControl();
    control.Media = media1;
    control.Play();
}
```

The Issue is that the file is created, but its not playable.
I am looking for the command to save the H264 stream to a mp4 file **without** decoding it.
any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to use MF for this? MFNet project is not supported by its author anymore, and there are no official C# wrappers provided by MS. You probably can use COM Interop, but it would be easier to write a native component and call into it from your C# code. Also, there was a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071652/storing-rtsp-to-a-file-location), where [vlc bindings](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) were used to save stream to an mp4 file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I doesn't really matter to me which library or code to use, and it doesn't have to be a mp4 file. I have RTP Packets full of H264 (Payload Type 96) that I want to put in some container. Don't really know which containers are good for H264, I read some things about mp4, avi, mkv. any thoughts?

Comment: I would try VLCDotNet with the transcoding example from [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075250/997164) first.

Comment: i tried it, give an exception - "cannot set up option while media is not initialized yet". I edited the code in my question

Comment: You should put the port at the end of the rtsp address. "rtsp://localhost/live/Testing:554/h264". Check the path that the player is playing and use the same.

Comment: The vlc player plays the path: "rtsp://localhost/live/Testing" just fine. no need for port number. The code still gives exception..

Comment: @user1662033 Is the build of your project 32bit? It does not play on a 64bit

Comment: Yes it's 32bit.. In the build tab it's the platform target is: Any CPU. And the prefer 32-bit is enabled.

Comment: More than that - the vlc is able to play the source "rtsp://192.168.30.11/1.mkv" from the other PC (without me making a server on my PC, directly from source) , and the code throws the exception

Comment: @Vinshi I just realized that I needed to do some initializing before everything. see my code for the change. the problem now is that a file is created, bit its not playable. any ideas?

Comment: @user1662033 Try stopping the vlc player after a time period. `control.stop()` should do the trick.

Comment: @Vinshi I don't want to play it when I run the app on the From. I want to save it to a mp4 or any other video file format. I just don't know what to put in the AddOption method to convert the raw H264 stream to a video file. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing the stream in the background as a process.

```
Process vlc;
vlc = Process.Start("C://Program Files//Videolan//VLC//VLC.exe", "rtsp://192.168.30.11/1.mkv\" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C://folder//filename.mp4,no-overwrite}");
Thread.Sleep(9000);
vlc.kill();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is it possible that you made a mistake with the parameters that you give the Process.Start? because the whole command ("--qt-start.... sout=#transcode") is not passed as a String.. just making sure the parameters should be passed like this